# Why do I get Error 400: access_not_configured in my app's Google Oauth2 Login process? How to fix it?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We are using Google OAuth2 for Moodle's login. It was working for all our users for their institution mail IDs so far. But today one of the school with mail id: username@thexxxschool.in are getting the following error while trying to login using Google's Oauth2:
[image]

Why am I getting this error all of sudden? And how to fix it?

When I open the Google Cloud Console, I get this in the OAuth Consent screen:

[image]

I did not change anything as the app is already is being used by the users. Does this have anything to do with the error? I already have the App in the Google's playstore, would changing these settings in the OAuth Consent Screen affect my users from logging in?

Thanks!